# "if choice..." continues onto the next "if choice..."

Tags: python

Hello i'm fairly new to python and am having trouble with a segment of my code. After one "if" statement my code carries onto the next "if" statement when I don't want it to. I have tried elif but it has come up with invalid syntax.

```
 print(
    """

    Flash Card Quiz

    0 - Show Keywords
    1 - Take the Test
    2 - Exit
    """
    )

choice = input("Choice: ")
    print()

    #ShowKeywords
    if choice == "0":
        fp = open('keywords.txt')
        while 1:
            line = fp.readline()
            if not line:
                break
            print (line)

    # TaketheTest
    if choice == "1":
        print("Here is your Keyword")
    import random
    with open('keywords_1.txt') as f:
         a = random.choice(list(f)).strip()
         print ("    ")
         print ("------", a)
```

This is what is showing

```
fibre,A nutrient that cannot be digested.


------ photosynthesis
Here are your options, select A, B or C, whichever is correct.

Press the enter key to continue.
```

After "fibre,A nutrient that cannot be digested." I would like it to go back to the choice menu. How would I do this please?

Comment: You can use while loop to continue the above.

Comment: I haven't used that before, please could you expand?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the second `if` to the `elif` and move everything below it to the same indentation level as `print`:

```
elif choice == "1":
    print("Here is your Keyword")
    import random
    with open('keywords_1.txt') as f:
        a = random.choice(list(f)).strip()
        print ("    ")
        print ("------", a)
```

**Edit:** If you wish to let the user to make another choice after he(she) made their first choice, then wrap all the code you've provided into the `while True:` loop and add the couple of new options:

```
elif choice == "2":
    break
else:
    print('Incorrect option')
```

And read [the following article](http://docs.python.org/release/2.5.1/ref/indentation.html) very carefully - it explains how the indentation in Python works.

Comment: It outputs exactly the same

Comment: Have you indented the lines below? Python uses whitespace to manage scope, so if your indentation is wrong then your code is wrong.

Comment: It is no longer printing the next if statement however it's not going back to the menu.

Answer (score 0):

It is like this,

```
print(
"""

Flash Card Quiz

0 - Show Keywords
1 - Take the Test
2 - Exit
"""
)
while True:
    choice = input("Choice: ")
    print()

    #ShowKeywords
    if choice == "0":
        fp = open('keywords.txt')
        while True:
            line = fp.readline()
            if not line:
                break
            print (line)

    # TaketheTest
    elif choice == "1":
        print("Here is your Keyword")
    import random
    with open('keywords_1.txt') as f:
        a = random.choice(list(f)).strip()
        print ("    ")
        print ("------", a)
```

Comment: How can I now close the program with the choice == 2?

Comment: before `import random` just add following
`elif choice == '2':
     sys.exit(0)`